# Firebase : 2 Webview on Google login with Cordova

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im using Firebase 4.1.1 javascript with Cordova 7.0.1.
My Android and iOS app needs to login using Facebook or Google but the Google login do something strange. After the Google login, it starts another webview so I can see 2 webview of my application in Google Chrome inspect and I dont seems to be logged.

My code:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('profile');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
   firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(authData) {
   ...
 }); });
```

I have also followed the instruction here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

My Facebook login works perfectly, does anyone already see this problem with Google login?

Thanks

Comment: This setting could be the issue: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode. Try setting launchMode to singleInstance.

Comment: I dont know how to change that. But why it's working with the Facebook login? I suppose that if it was a setting issue, it will not working on Facebook as well, no?

Comment: I have seen developers having similar issues. Changing launchMode seemed to fix it: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/168

Comment: Great! Thanks!! Is there a way to add something in the config.xml to modify this parameter? Because every time I launch: cordova prepare android, the modification disappear.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748570/how-should-i-define-launchmode-in-androidmanifest-xml-using-phonegap-jqm

Comment: wow, you made my day! Thanks a lot for your help!